# Controlling several textFields from MaterialUI in React

Tags: reactjs

I need help getting more than one textfield to update but the events are clashing. When I update one field it alters or removes the other. This is my code now

```
class ClientConn extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: '192.168.60.51',
            value2: '8080',
            value3: 'ContentManager',
            defaultToggled: true,
        };
    }

    handle1Change = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            value: event.target.value,
        });
    };

    handle2Change = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            value2: event.target.value2,
        });
    };

    handle3Change = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            value3: event.target.value3,
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <TextField
                    id="host-address"
                    value={this.state.value}
                    onChange={this.handle1Change}
                />
                <TextField
                    id="port"
                    value={this.state.value2}
                    onChange={this.handle2Change}
                />
                <TextField
                    id="folder"
                    value={this.state.value3}
                    onChange={this.handle3Change}
                />
            </div>      
            <div>
                 {this.state.defaultToggled ? "https://" : "http://"}{this.state.value}:{this.state.value2}/{this.state.value3}
            </div>
        </div>
     );
   }
}
```

They pre-populate fine. Like this

> https://192.168.60.51:8080/ContentManager

I need to be able to update each field and it will update that link's respective value on-the-fly before I send it to the server/database. So if I change the port from 8080 to 8088, it will update the link as I type. Same with the folder and even the host address.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isnt it?

```
 handle1Change = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            value: event.target.value,
        });
    };

    handle2Change = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            value2: event.target.value,
        });
    };

    handle3Change = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            value3: event.target.value,
        });
    };
```

Looks like by mistake you have given `value2 in handle2change` and `value3 in handle3change`

Comment: Awesome! I had a feeling it was something easy and stupid lol. Thanks!